# How can you debug a coldfusion script that doesn't render HTML or run javascript?

Tags: ajax, debugging, coldfusion, server-side

I'm using a JavaScript plugin to upload files to a ColdFusion app.
It uses AJAX to communicate with the server and expects JSON in return. (pretty standard)
I have two cfm scripts.

The first contains the form for the plugin.

The second handles the actual uploading, deleting, returning file lists, etc.

The second script returns JSON as plain text for the plugin to process.

The second script renders no HTML and the JSON sent back to the first script is fed straight into the js plugin.

Everything works perfectly actually.
I've gotten it to upload files and return file lists.

my problem:
As the second script's code gets more complicated it's getting much harder to debug.

It renders no code, so cfdump is useless.

I'm poking around in the dark with no error messages or other info to let me know why something isn't working.

my limitations:
The plugin is large and complicated and I don't want to mess with it if I don't have to.
And I shouldn't have to mess with it because it works perfectly, it's my cf code that's the problem.

I also don't have access to the admin area for this project.

But I need some way to log or debug this code.

my solutions:
I've been doing cfdump to a third file, but this is a less than ideal solution as I'm spending half my time coding and half my time changing the cfdump solution to suit new needs. And also evolving my cfdump logger to handle different situations. I don't want to reinvent the wheel by writing my own logger though, I just want to code.
I got my admin to install the AJAX logger not realizing it's meant to log JavaScript, not ColdFusion. So that's not working either.

I know that people have worked with ColdFusion for AJAX. I can't be the only one having this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What browser are you using? Are you able to dump out to the ajax response for debugging and view with the browser console?

Comment: Can you dump any values or errors you need to view for debugging to the ajax response and view the response body via Chromes "Developer Tools" > "Network"?  I'm not sure I fully understand your problem, but does this resolve it for you?

Comment: I'm using Chrome and Firefox. That might be a solution. But even if I know what I'm getting back, it still won't tell me what's breaking down if I get nothing back. The Ajax part is easyish, it's the basic flow control problems and silly bugs in the second script that are invisible to me that cause the real problem.

Comment: The problem is that I have a page that's running pure server-side code and not rendering HTML and I want to debug it. If something goes wonky, I can't just do a cfdump at the point where it might be breaking because I'll never see the dump. Maybe I've missed something but there seems to be no other way to debug your code in cf. Plus any homebrew solutions compound the problem as I don't know whether it's the script or the debugging solution that's breaking.

Comment: You will see the dump, anything you output with `cfoutput`, or the error in the response in the network section of the console.

Comment: Thanks jk. The problem is that I'm not calling the script directly (via url). It's being called by a javascript plugin via AJAX. The javascript doesn't render the response, so cfoutput doesn't work. And the javascript itself works fine, so nothing errors in the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget the simple and powerful `<cflog>` tag. You can dump variables at any point in your code and if you want to dump a structure, you can use `serializeJSON(someStruct)` to see the entire structure (or object converted to a structure) in your logs. Combine that with the tail view in Eclipse/CFBuilder, and you have a real-time stream of the inner workings of your non-HTML generating code.

Comment: Thanks. One of my limitations was a lack of access to the logs in the admin panel as I'm doing this remotely on a very secure system. But your advice sounded best so I looked deeper and it worked in combination with this tutorial: http://colorblindprogramming.com/how-to-read-coldfusion-log-files-directly-from-your-app

Comment: Thanks for the link to that tip. Very handy for reading logs on servers where you don't have direct access to the logs!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Firefox the install Firebug on it. In the console tab you can see all the Ajax request, expand the request go to the 'HTML' tab. In the 'HTML' tab you will able to see the Html template created by the server page(your second script) and there you will also able to find the coldfusion error. Firebug is a great tool to work with the Ajax, hope this will help you also.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `<cftry>` and mail the error with `<cfmail type="html" ...><cfdump ...` to get insight into your script.

Example:

```
<CFTRY>
    <CFSET thingsmightgowronghere &= "foo" />
    <CFCATCH type="any">
        <CFMAIL from="debug@example.com" to="you@yours.com" subject="#cfcatch.Message#" type="html"><CFDUMP var="#cfcatch#" /></CFMAIL>
    </CFCATCH>
</CFTRY>
```

Debugging with firebug would also be possible, but if you cfdump something and look at it in firebug its not that comfortable to crawl through the css/js which cfdump creates.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious about the belief that cfdump is unavailable due to lack of html tags.  I created a page with only this code:

```
<cfsetting showdebugoutput="no">
<cfset foo = "bar">
<cfdump var="#foo#">
```

And when I browsed it, the word "bar" appeared in the browser.